# How to dynamically create this json format?

Tags: json, sql-server, database

**Hello everyone, good work first,**

I want to create a json model like the one below.

**1-** Data name has been created historically here. I don't know how to create it, how is this possible?

**2-** My other question is, how can I store this data in a database in a table?

**Thanks** to everyone already.

```
10/01/2020": {
"Confirmed": 0,
"Recovered": 0,
"Death": 0 },


"11/01/2020": {
"Confirmed": 0,
"Recovered": 0,
"Death": 0},
```

...

Comment: Are you using any programming language?  How did you get this input?  Will any users give the input or just you (DBA)?

Comment: This statement is made through an API. I want to take the statements that continue this way and save them in the database again. But what kind of table should this condition be stored in? I use c # as the programming language and mssql as the database.

As a return, I want to return a json data like this. But I do not understand how the date field is called as data name or title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table dbo.HospitalAdmissionStat
(
thedate date,
confirmed int,
recovered int,
death int,
createdutc datetime2(3) constraint dfcreatedutcmydata default(sysutcdatetime())
index clidxthedate clustered (thedate)
);

--go


declare @json nvarchar(max) = N'{
"10/01/2020": {
"Confirmed": 10,
"Recovered": 10,
"Death": 0 },

"11/01/2020": {
"Confirmed": 11,
"Recovered": 1,
"Death": 1}, 

"12/01/2020": {
"Confirmed": 12,
"Recovered": 2,
"Death": 2}, 

"13/01/2020": {
"Confirmed": 13,
"Recovered": 3,
"Death": 3},

"14/01/2020": {
"Confirmed": 14,
"Recovered": 0,
"Death": 0}

}
';

insert into dbo.HospitalAdmissionStat(thedate, confirmed, recovered, death)
select convert(date, dt.[key], 103) as thedate, v.Confirmed, v.Recovered, v.Death
from openjson(@json) as dt
cross apply openjson(dt.[value])
with
(
Confirmed int,
Recovered int,
Death int
) as v
order by thedate;

select *
from dbo.HospitalAdmissionStat;
```

Comment: Thank you soo much